# CRM Plugin: Calculate the value of a field as the difference between two other fields

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have 36 fields, aligned in line by 3, so I have 12 lines. For each line I have the need to plot the `field3` as the difference between `field1` - `field2`. This operation must be repeated for each row. My difficulty lies in the fact that I am new in the world of CRM and I cannot find a solution or a guide. I attach a small schema and my current code. Furthermore all the fields have different names, the scheme should make the idea. I cannot even look for type because they all have the same type.

Schema:

```
field1   field2    field3 = field1-field2
field4   field5    field6 = field4-field5
field7   field8    field9 = field7-field8
etc.
```

The code:

```
public class BudgetingOnChangeUpdateOffset : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
            context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (entity.LogicalName != "budgeting")
                return;

            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            try
            {
                var budget = (Money)entity.Attributes["budget"];
                var consumptive = (Money)entity.Attributes["cons"];
                var offset = budget.Value - consumptive.Value;
                entity.Attributes["offset"] = offset;

                service.Update(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("MyPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

(1) When a plugin triggers on an Update step, it will send only the field that triggered the plugin. To get additional fields you can either pass them in via an Image which you configure on the plugin step, or do a retrieve to get the columns you want.

In the code you have here, it seems that you need to get the values of the fields on which you're doing the calculations.

If you're running this plugin on Create, you can either use a Post-image with all the fields or do a seperate Retrieve operation to get all the fields. (Create steps cannot use a Pre-image because the record has yet to be created in the database)

For more info on pre- and post-images see:

[Utilising Pre/Post Entity Images in a Dynamics CRM Plugin](https://crmchap.co.uk/utilising-prepost-entity-images-in-a-dynamics-crm-plugin/)

[Pre image and Post image in Dynamics crm Plugins : Advanced Plugin concepts Part 1](http://www.magnifez.com/pre-image-and-post-image-in-dynamics-crm-plugins-advanced-plugin-concepts-part-1/)

(2) I like to build and debug my plugin logic in a Console App before using it in a plugin. To connect a console app to CRM use an instance of the CrmServiceClient class, which is in the [XrmTooling NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/).

The way I generally handle this is to put all the logic into a Shared Project, which reference from both the Console App and the Plugin. But, be aware that this approach relies on using a Retrieve to get the necessary data from the target entity, rather than an Image from the Plugin.

(3) If you are going to develop it straight as a plugin you might want to familiarize yourself with the Tracing Service and [plugin trace logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx#loggingandtracing).

(4) It is beyond the scope of this answer, but you may also want to research the concepts of "early-bound" vs. "late-bound" development in Dynamics 365. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602917.aspx#.NET%20Development:%20Use%20Dynamics%20365%20SDK%20assemblies) has some info about that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like straight forward.

1.Register this plugin step on Pre-Operation stage, remove the line `service.Update(entity);`. Below lines of code will take care of calculation of difference between two fields & put it in third field as needed in the same execution pipeline (database update). No need of extra update call.

```
var budget = (Money)entity.Attributes["budget"];
var consumptive = (Money)entity.Attributes["cons"];
var offset = budget.Value - consumptive.Value;
entity.Attributes["offset"] = offset;

var field4 = (Money)entity.Attributes["field4"];
var field5 = (Money)entity.Attributes["field5"];
var field6 = field4.Value - field5.Value;
entity.Attributes["field6"] = field6;
```

2.Choose only field1, field2, field4, field5 as **filtering attributes** in plugin step - so plugin trigger only on update of those fields & not on all fields

Like Aron explained, register the PreImage values so that you will get all the unupdated fields to calculate in plugin.